# Characterizing sequences $a(k)$ satisfying $\frac{1}{k} a(k)\log a(k)\to \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For context, I am interested in characterizing the growth of positive and strictly increasing sequences $a(k)$ such that the series
$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{x^k}{\Gamma(a(k))}$$
converges for any $x\in\mathbb{C}$. By the root test, we see that we need $\lim_{k\to\infty}|\Gamma(a(k))|^{-1/k}=0$. By the asymptotics for the Gamma function, we thus require that $a(k)^{-a(k)/k}\to 0$, in other words $e^{-a(k)\log a(k)/k}\to 0$, *i.e.* $\frac{1}{k}a(k)\log a(k)\to\infty.$

I am hoping for precise characterizations of the set
$$\mathcal{A}=\left\{a(k):\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}:\frac{k}{a(k)\log a(k)}\to 0\right\}.$$
To fix notation, we say $f_k=\Omega(g_k)$ if $g_k=O(f_k)$. For example, it is clear that we have the inclusion $\Omega(b_k:=k)\subset \mathcal{A}$. But do we have that $\mathcal{A}\subset \Omega(k)$?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I forgot a minus sign in the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly those sequences for which
$$a(k)=\omega\left(\frac{k}{\log k}\right),$$
where $f(x)=\omega(g(x))$ if $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$.

Indeed, letting $b(k)=k/\log k$,
$$a(k)=\omega(b(k))\Longleftrightarrow a(k)\log a(k)=\omega(b(k)\log b(k)),$$
and
$$b(k)\log b(k)=\frac{k}{\log k}\log\left(\frac k{\log k}\right)=\frac{k\log k-k\log\log k}{\log k}=k(1-o(1))=\Theta(k).$$

Comment: Thank you. As a follow up questions, is it true, like I assumed in my post that $\Gamma(a(k))^{-1/k}\to 0 \iff a(k)^{-a(k)/k} \to 0$?