# When is it true that $\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{x^k}{\Gamma(1+a(k))}\sim\int_0^\infty \frac{x^t}{\Gamma(1+a(t))}\,dt$ as $x\to\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, asymptotics

First, some notation. I'll write $f(x)=o(g(x))$ if $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=0$. I'll also write $g(x)=\omega(f(x))$ if $f(x)=o(g(x))$, *i.e.* $\limsup_{x\to\infty} \left|\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}\right|=\infty$. I'll say $f(x)\sim g(x)$ as $x\to\infty$ if $f(x)=g(x)+o(g(x))$ for all large enough $x$, *i.e.* $f(x)/g(x)=1+o(1)$ for all large enough $x$.

---

I'm interested in whether, given a certain class of sequence $a(k)$ (see below), we have that
$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{x^k}{\Gamma(1+a(k))}\sim\int_0^\infty \frac{x^t}{\Gamma(1+a(t))}\,dt$$
as $x\to\infty$. The sequence $a(k)$ is non-negative, increasing, and approaches $+\infty$ as $k\to\infty$ fast enough that the series on the left hand side converges for every real number $x\in[0,\infty)$—it turns out that this is equivalent to $a(k)=\omega\left(\frac{k}{\log k}\right)$ by [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611180/characterizing-sequences-ak-satisfying-frac1k-ak-log-ak-to-infty/4611182#4611182). I know this relationships holds true when $a(k):=k$ (see [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608789/asymptotics-of-int-0-infty-fracx2z-gamma1z-dz?noredirect=1#comment9718521_4608789), [[3]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437561/asymptotics-of-int-0-infty-fracx2z-gamma1z-dz-for-large-x/437601#437601)), in which case the series is simply $e^x$, as well as when $a(k):=2k$, in which case the series is $\cosh(\sqrt{x})$.

It seems tempting to use Euler-Maclaurin summation, but the resulting difference between the sum and the integral already ends up being a divergent series for large enough $x$ in the case $a(k):=k$.

Edit: Given feedback from MathOverflow, I require that $a(t)\in C^\infty$ on its domain $[0,\infty)$ and the sequence $a(k)$ is defined to be the restriction $a(k):\mathbb{N}_0\to[0,\infty)=a(t)|_{t\in\mathbb{N}_0}$.

This question is cross-posted at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437844/when-is-it-true-that-sum-k-ge-0-fracxk-gamma1ak-sim-int-0-infty).

Comment: I would suspect that any error between the series and integral is only amplified if $x$ is increased in magnitude, not diminished

Comment: Cross-posted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/437844/116247

Comment: Yes the absolute error will, but I am talking about the relative error here. Given $f(x)$ the integral in the post and $g(x)$ the series, I would like to know whether $f(x)=g(x)+o(g(x))$. This doesn't contradict the fact that the $o(g(x))$ term may still diverge. However, it is equivalent with the relative error $\left|\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(x)}\right|=\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-1\right|$ tending to zero.

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.iii)?

Comment: I haven't but it does look promising. Thank you.